# Retrofit fails to download binary file in an Android app – end result is a corrupted file that is larger than expected

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to download PDF files using Retrofit 2 on an Android app written in Kotlin. The snippet below is basically my entire code. Based on my log output, it appears that the file downloads successfully and saves to the intended location.

However, the downloaded file is larger than expected, and is corrupt. I can open it in a PDF reader, but the PDF is blank. In the example below, I tried downloading https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf. If I download this file through a browser, the result is a PDF that is 13,264 bytes. Downloaded with this code however, it is 22,503 bytes, about 70% larger than expected. I am getting a similar result for other binary files like JPEGs. However, downloading a TXT actually works fine, even a large one. So it seems like the problem is isolated to binary files.

```
package com.ebelinski.RetrofitTestApp

import android.app.Application
import android.content.Context
import android.os.Build
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import com.google.gson.FieldNamingPolicy
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient
import okhttp3.ResponseBody
import org.jetbrains.anko.doAsync
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.http.*
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import java.io.*
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

interface FileService {

    @Streaming
    @GET
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/pdf", "Accept: application/pdf")
    fun fileFromUrl(@Url url: String,
                    @Header("Authorization") tokenTypeWithAuthorization: String): Call<ResponseBody>

}

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    val TAG = "MainActivity"

    val RETROFIT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 60
    private val RETROFIT_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 60
    private val RETROFIT_WRITE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS = 60

    private val retrofit: Retrofit
        get() {
            val gson = GsonBuilder()
                .setDateFormat("yyyyMMdd")
                .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
                .create()

            val converterFactory = GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)

            val okHttpClient = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(RETROFIT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SECONDS.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .readTimeout(RETROFIT_READ_TIMEOUT_SECONDS.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .writeTimeout(RETROFIT_WRITE_TIMEOUT_SECONDS.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .addInterceptor { chain ->
                    val userAgentValue = "doesn't matter"
                    val originalRequest = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("User-Agent", userAgentValue).build()

                    var response = chain.proceed(originalRequest)
                    if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
                        val bodyString = response.body()!!.string()
                        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Sending request %s with headers %s ", originalRequest.url(), originalRequest.headers()))
                        Log.d(TAG, String.format("Got response HTTP %s %s \n\n with body %s \n\n with headers %s ", response.code(), response.message(), bodyString, response.headers()))
                        response = response.newBuilder().body(ResponseBody.create(response.body()!!.contentType(), bodyString)).build()
                    }

                    response
                }
                .build()

            return Retrofit.Builder()
                .callbackExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool())
                .baseUrl("https://example.com")
                .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build()
        }

    private val fileService: FileService = retrofit.create(FileService::class.java)

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        doAsync { downloadFile() }
    }

    fun downloadFile() {
        val uri = "https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf"
        val auth = "doesn't matter"

        val response = fileService.fileFromUrl(
            uri,
            auth
        ).execute()

        if (!response.isSuccessful) {
            Log.e(TAG, "response was not successful: " +
                    response.code() + " -- " + response.message())
            throw Throwable(response.message())
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Server has file for ${uri}")
        saveFileFromResponseBody(response.body()!!)
    }



    // Returns the name of what the file should be, whether or not it exists locally
    private fun getFileName(): String? {
        return "dummy.pdf"
    }

    fun saveFileFromResponseBody(body: ResponseBody): Boolean {
        val fileName = getFileName()
        val localFullFilePath = File(getFileFullDirectoryPath(), fileName)
        var inputStream: InputStream? = null
        var outputStream: OutputStream? = null
        Log.d(TAG, "Attempting to download $fileName")

        try {
            val fileReader = ByteArray(4096)
            val fileSize = body.contentLength()
            var fileSizeDownloaded: Long = 0

            inputStream = body.byteStream()
            outputStream = FileOutputStream(localFullFilePath)

            while (true) {
                val read = inputStream.read(fileReader)
                if (read == -1) break

                outputStream.write(fileReader, 0, read)
                fileSizeDownloaded += read.toLong()

                Log.d(TAG, "$fileName download progress: $fileSizeDownloaded of $fileSize")
            }

            outputStream.flush()
            Log.d(TAG, "$fileName downloaded successfully")
            return true
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.d(TAG, "$fileName downloaded attempt failed")
            return false
        } finally {
            inputStream?.close()
            outputStream?.close()
        }
    }

    fun getFileFullDirectoryPath(): String {
        val directory = getDir("test_dir", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        return directory.absolutePath
    }
}
```

If it helps, here's my `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ebelinski.RetrofitTestApp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.0'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose problem is not with Retrofit, but with your OkHTTP3 interceptor, specifically here:

```
val bodyString = response.body()!!.string()
```

Here are string() contents:

```
  /**
   * Returns the response as a string.
   *
   * If the response starts with a
   * [Byte Order Mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), it is consumed and
   * used to determine the charset of the response bytes.
   *
   * Otherwise if the response has a `Content-Type` header that specifies a charset, that is used
   * to determine the charset of the response bytes.
   *
   * Otherwise the response bytes are decoded as UTF-8.
   *
   * This method loads entire response body into memory. If the response body is very large this
   * may trigger an [OutOfMemoryError]. Prefer to stream the response body if this is a
   * possibility for your response.
   */
  @Throws(IOException::class)
  fun string(): String = source().use { source ->
    source.readString(charset = source.readBomAsCharset(charset()))
  }
```

You can check ResponseBody [source code](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/53ba4dd9efcb0b469e86eca9d865e64cce950ad4/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/ResponseBody.kt) for more details.

Suppose using body.source() instead would help. 
(or just avoid intercepting binary files)

Good interceptor implementation example is here:
[HTTPLoggingInterceptor](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp-logging-interceptor/src/main/java/okhttp3/logging/HttpLoggingInterceptor.kt).

Comment: Thank you so much! That was exactly my problem. I removed that part of the interceptor and it worked as expected.